# Can't create protection rule with pattern

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to automatically add some protection rules to all our GitHub repositories via the REST API. For that purpose I am using [this reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branch-protection?apiVersion=2022-11-28). I had no trouble setting a rule for a specific branch, such as `master` or `development`, however I am trying to create a rule based on a pattern, e.g. `release/*`.

I can easily do it through GitHub web UI:

[image]

however I can't do it with the REST API as it seems that it's targeting against a specific branch. How can I achieve this?

Comment: From the link you posted (emphasis mine): _"The name of the branch. Cannot contain wildcard characters. To use wildcard characters in branch names, **use the GraphQL API**."_

Answer (score 1):

From same documentation:

> `branch`
>
> The name of the branch. Cannot contain wildcard characters. To use wildcard characters in branch names, use the [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql).

Please refer to [GraphQL API CreateBranchProtectionRuleInput](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/input-objects#createbranchprotectionruleinput)